# Get video duration (contentDetails) with Youtube JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I've been trying to get a video duration with Youtube JavaScript API v3, this is the relevant part of my JS:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            q: 'eminem',
            part: 'snippet'
    });

    request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
        $('#results').empty()
        var srchItems = response.result.items;     

        $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
            vidTitle = item.snippet.title;
            vidTime = item.contentDetails.duration;
            vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;               
            $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidTime +'</pre>');                      
        });  
    });
```

The problem is in `vidTime = item.contentDetails.duration;` and console returns the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined

But, i'm looking the JSON structure returned in the request ([See Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)) and it was to be working, and I don't know why i'm getting this error :(

I've tried to change the `part` to: `part: snippet, contentDetails` but with this change i've more errors...

So, how to do to fix this?

**EDITED**

To analyze the return of `console.log(response);` I could see that the contentDetails is not returned in the array, but then how can I get the video duration?

Comment: You are right that you have to include `contentDetails` in `part`. Can you post the errors that you get when extending `part` to read like `part: 'snippet,contentDetails'`?

Comment: The following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Comment: Okay, that means that the `response` does not carry anything in the `result` attribute. To debug further, what does it show in the developer tools if you log `response`, i.e. `request.execute(function(response)  { console.log(response); });`

Comment: @sthzg I followed your tip and analyze the return on the console could see that the contentDetails is not returned in the array, but then how can I get the video duration?

Comment: Okay, then this answer seems to help further: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27415212/870769

Comment: Solved with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393842/contentdetails-or-duration-not-coming-using-youtube-v3-api/27415212#27415212

Answer (score 0):

Your request only includes part: snippet. You have to also include contentDetails.

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        q: 'eminem',
        part: 'snippet,contentDetails'
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but, if I add "contentDetails on my part I've the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Comment: I don't use gapi myself, but since you are trying to access item.contentDetails, you need to add contentDetails to your search parameter.